# Unwanted shifting using fixed column and rowspan in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that uses `rowspan` for one of the table headers. This table also switches to a fixed column style on smaller sizes. The issue I'm running into is on smaller sizes, when the `th` with the `rowspan` becomes fixed, it messes up the structure of the remaning `th`.

A solution I thought of was to just have an empty `th` above Foods so I didn't have to use a `rowspan`, but due to ADA requirments, that's not an option.

Here's some code: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/itsclarke/pen/mggzoO)

This is the large screen view - you can see there's a Foods column as well as two groups, each of which containing two columns.
[image]

Here's a view of when it goes to the fixed column layout. You can see that Group 1 - Col 1 now takes the place where Foods used to be, and the entire 2nd shifted.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" class="fixed">Foods</th>
        <th colspan="2">Group 1</th>
        <th colspan="2">Group 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed">Tacos</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed">Pizza</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 900px;
}

th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-left: solid 1px grey;
}

th[colspan="2"] {
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
}

td {
  border-top: solid 1px grey;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: grey;
}

.fixed {
  border-left: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .fixed {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0;
  }

  .wrap {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: When it comes to making a responsive layout, tables are notoriously difficult to work with. A much easier solution would be to use CSS grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure about the issue but it seems to be related to the use of `position:fixed`. You are removing the elements from the flow so it's like they no more belong to the table making the table algorithm behave strange.

An idea of fix is to consider a extra element that you make visible on small screen to avoid this issue. Basically this element will correct the table layout when you make some of the element `position:fixed`

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 900px;
}

th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-left: solid 1px grey;
}

th[colspan="2"] {
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
}

td {
  border-top: solid 1px grey;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: grey;
}

.fixed {
  border-left: none;
}

.fix {
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}
@media (min-width:700px) {
.fix {
  display:none;
}
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .fixed {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .wrap {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" class="fixed">Foods</th>
        <th colspan="2">Group 1</th>
        <th colspan="2">Group 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="fix"></th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed">Tacos</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed">Pizza</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

To avoid extra element you can consider pseudo element:

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 900px;
}

th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-left: solid 1px grey;
}

th[colspan="2"] {
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
}

td {
  border-top: solid 1px grey;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: grey;
}

.fixed {
  border-left: none;
}

thead > tr:last-child::before {
  content:"";
  display:table-cell;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}
@media (min-width:700px) {
thead > tr:last-child::before {
  display:none;
}
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .fixed {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .wrap {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" class="fixed">Foods</th>
        <th colspan="2">Group 1</th>
        <th colspan="2">Group 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed">Tacos</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed">Pizza</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
        <td>blank</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Unfortunately it still uses an empty cell to make it work, but it's the closest solution I've come across. You may want to update your answer to `display: inline; display: initial` so it works in IE as well.

Comment: @itsclarke try `table-cell` instead of `initial` it seems the last isn't supported in IE, will update the answer

Comment: @itsclarke check the update, you can avoid the extra element with a pseudo element